# Neural Network training data normalisation vs. runtime input data

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I'm starting to learn about neural networks and I came across data normalisation. I understand the need for it but I don't quite know what to do with my data once my model is trained and in the field.

Let say I take my input data, subtract its mean and divide by the standard deviation. Then I take that as inputs and I train my neural network.

Once in the field, what do I do with my input sample on which I want a prediction?

Do I need to keep my training data mean and standard deviation and use that to normalise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  The mean and standard deviation that you use to normalize the training data will be the same that you use to normalize the testing data (i.e, don't compute a mean and standard deviation for the test data).

Hopefully this link will give you more helpful info: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

> An important point to make about the preprocessing is that any preprocessing statistics (e.g. the data mean) must only be computed on the training data, and then applied to the validation / test data. E.g. computing the mean and subtracting it from every image across the entire dataset and then splitting the data into train/val/test splits would be a mistake. Instead, the mean must be computed only over the training data and then subtracted equally from all splits (train/val/test).